# MatTable OR filter

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2, angular6

Is it possible to have an or filter on a MatTable?  Imagine I have two separate search boxes, and I would like to filter if there is a match on either of them.  Is there a way to do this out of the box?  Or would I need to create a custom filter predicate?  Thanks!

EDIT.  E.g. if I have a text input, and a date picker, how could I check to see if there is something in the table that matches either the text, and/or the date, using the filter?

Comment: refer this link to add filter for MatTable - https://stackblitz.com/angular/aepvdydpvpl?file=app%2Ftable-filtering-example.ts

Comment: I know how to add a filter, what I am wondering is if it is possible to add a filter that searches for two things simultaneously like an OR.  e.g. if I have 2 text input boxes, I'd like to be able to filter on if an item matches one OR the other

Comment: for that you have to declare two different variable and bind with each one of input box respectively, after that make one common function for perform search and in that function use if else condition to perform search

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve or filter for MatTable using below code.

for ts file

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material';

export interface PeriodicElement {
  name: string;
  position: number;
  weight: number;
  symbol: string;
}

const ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [
  {position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H'},
  {position: 2, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He'},
  {position: 3, name: 'Lithium', weight: 6.941, symbol: 'Li'},
  {position: 4, name: 'Beryllium', weight: 9.0122, symbol: 'Be'},
  {position: 5, name: 'Boron', weight: 10.811, symbol: 'B'},
  {position: 6, name: 'Carbon', weight: 12.0107, symbol: 'C'},
  {position: 7, name: 'Nitrogen', weight: 14.0067, symbol: 'N'},
  {position: 8, name: 'Oxygen', weight: 15.9994, symbol: 'O'},
  {position: 9, name: 'Fluorine', weight: 18.9984, symbol: 'F'},
  {position: 10, name: 'Neon', weight: 20.1797, symbol: 'Ne'},
];

/**
 * @title Table with filtering
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'table-filtering-example',
  styleUrls: ['table-filtering-example.css'],
  templateUrl: 'table-filtering-example.html',
})
export class TableFilteringExample {
  search1: string;
  search2: string;
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol'];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(ELEMENT_DATA);

  applyFilter() {
    this.dataSource.filter = this.search1.trim().toLowerCase();

    if(this.dataSource.filteredData.length == 0){
        this.dataSource.filter = this.search2.trim().toLowerCase();
    }
  }
}
```

For html file

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter()" placeholder="Filter 1" [(ngModel)]="search1">
</mat-form-field>
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter()" placeholder="Filter 2" [(ngModel)]="search2">
</mat-form-field>
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">

  <!-- Position Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Name Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Weight Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Symbol Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Symbol </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.symbol}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```